# change $src from wp_register_script in plugins/themes

Tags: scripts

I have a lot of plugins using external scripts from googleapis - these are throttled/blocked in China and it causes a lot of problems. Without rewriting the lines in all the plugins/themes and break my upgrade path, is there a way we can do it in my themes function.php file so I rewrite all the $src urls to local urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well of course you can. All you need to find is what handle they are using for those scripts. let's say they are uing plugin-script handle. Then you deregister and register script again with your URL. Like this.

```
function wcs_scripts_styles() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'plugin-script' );
    wp_register_script( 'plugin-script', get_stylesheet_uri(). '/js/jquery.script.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcs_scripts_styles' );
```

This will replace script location to script hosted in you theme js folder.

Comment: Excellent, thanks - so I can just override the handle. Nice!

Comment: Yes you can. And if this solution worked for you, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: what if the registered script has some vars in it from `wp_localize_script`, who do I retrieve them?

Answer (score 0):

If one only wants to consider overriding the `src` for the registered script without copying the localized array and script dependencies, you can modify it using [`wp_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_scripts/)

```php
function my_scripts_styles() {
    $wp_scripts = wp_scripts();

    if ( isset( $wp_scripts->registered['script-handler'] ) ) {
        $wp_scripts->registered['script-handler']->src = plugins_url(
            '/assets/js/my-script.js',
            __FILE__
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_styles', 11 );
```